# ES6 features Destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

by using es6 feature that is destructing , in objects if we made some methods so we can extract that methods also , as property we can , as i try by doing this , please have a look on above code

```js
let person = {
  name: "Ravi",
  favGames: ["cricket", "Badminton", "Tennis"],
  displayFavGames() {
    this.favGames.forEach(game => {
      console.log("My gave game " + game)
    })
  }
}
person.displayFavGames();

let displayData = ({
  name,
  favGames,
  displayFavGames
}) => {
  return `My name is ${name} and my cofavourite games is 
                    ${displayFavGames}`;
}

console.log(displayData(person));
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for help with.   Please tell us exactly what the question is.

Comment: `displayFavGames` is a function. You're not calling the function, you're just interpolating the function definition into the template string.

Comment: I see a statement and code but no question.

Answer (score 2):

`displayFavGames` is a function, so you need to call it.

But since it's a property of the object and uses `this`, you need to call it using property notation: `object.displayFavGames()`. You can do that if you destructure the argument, because you don't have a variable that refers to the original object. You can get the argument as a single variable, then use destructuring when initializing local variables.

And if you want to substitute the result of that function, it needs to return a string, not use `console.log()`.

```js
let person = {
  name: "Ravi",
  favGames: ["cricket", "Badminton", "Tennis"],
  displayFavGames() {
    return this.favGames.join("\n                    ");
  }
}
person.displayFavGames();

let displayData = (p) => {
  let {
    name,
    favGames,
    displayFavGames
  } = p;
  return `My name is ${name} and my cofavourite games are 
                    ${p.displayFavGames()}`;
}

console.log(displayData(person));
```

Answer (score 0):

`displayFavGames` is a function, while you can destructure it you need to call it which is not seem to achieve what you intend. Instead you can display the actuall favGames values.

```
let displayData = ({
  name,
  favGames      
}) => {
  return `My name is ${name} and my cofavourite games is 
                    ${favGames.join(",")}`;
}    
console.log(displayData(person));
```